# How to address someone in an email who referred to themselves as part of a department

Tags: business-japanese

Recently I received an email from someone in the editing department of a literary magazine. Specifically, they ended their email with:

```
[Magazine name] 編集部
```

For when I write them a response, how should I address them? How about this?

```
編集部の方、
```

Comment: Did they not sign their name in the email?

Comment: I think yes. ”[manazie name]編集部の方（々）｛かたがた｝へ” would be more polite?

Comment: Correct, they didn't give their name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another **very** common way to do this is to write:

> (Company/Publisher Name)
>
> (Magazine Name)  編集部御中{へんしゅうぶおんちゅう}
>
> ご担当者様{たんとうしゃさま}

It would look better with that last line than without.

NOTE: You ***cannot*** use 「～～部の方」 in addressing mail -- snail or electronic.

Answer (score 1):

[Magazine name] 編集部 御中　would be my suggestion for a formal correspondence. 御中{おんちゅう} is for when you are uncertain of the individual's name.